# Euler Maclaurin of a function with discontinuous derivative .

Tags: continuity, numerical-calculus, euler-maclaurin

I need to find the Euler Maclaurin summation of a function that can be generalized as the sinc function. $$\frac{\sin(f(x))}{f(x)}$$

But the sinc's function derivative is undefined at zero, which is present across the values of $f(x)$, and so I am wondering if I utilized the central difference differential method to serve as a limiting continuous differentiation for the sinc function will the Euler Maclaurin value still be accurate?

$$\operatorname{sinc}(x)$$

Central difference:$$\frac{\operatorname{sinc}(f(x+0.0001)) - \operatorname{sinc}(f(x-0.0001))}{0.0002}$$

Comment: $\text{sinc}(x)=1-\frac{x^2}{6}+\frac{x^4}{120}-\frac{x^6}{5040}+O\left(x^8\right)$ For $\text{sinc}(f(x))$ think about the chain rule

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici the values of f(x) also gets really high 10^10 and would need so many terms to approximate it correctly via Fourier series.

Comment: $\text{sinc}$ derivative is not undefined at $0$, we have $\text{sinc}'(0)=0$.

Comment: @jjagmath this is obvious via numerical differentiation thanks, I'll just stick to numerical differentials to find the value of the Euler Maclaurin summation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But the sinc's function derivative is undefined at zero,

$\def\sinc{\operatorname{sinc}}$It's straight forward enough to fix the singularity of $\sinc$ at 0, starting with the McLaurin series of $\sin$:

$$\begin{align}
\sinc x = \frac{\sin x}x
&= \frac1x\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!} \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n+1)!} \tag 1\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\sinc^{(n)}(0)}{n!}x^n \tag 2\\
\end{align}$$
By comparing coefficients of $(1)$ and $(2)$ you will find the needed $n$-th derivative of $\sinc$ at 0:

$$\sinc^{(n)}(0) = \begin{cases}
0, & \text{ if } n \text{ is odd} \\
(-1)^m\dfrac{1}{n+1}, & \text{ if } n=2m \text{ is even} \\
\end{cases}$$